# Dotting a Sphere

Tags: geometry, rotations, spheres, tiling

What is the maximum number of points that you can place symmetrically on the
surface of a sphere which cannot all be contained within two planes?

"Symmetrically" here means that, for any given start point and any given
target point, you can rotate the sphere around to get the same set of point
positions (over all points, not just start and target) with start now at
target.

My current maximum uses the bucky-ball with 60 points.

(I require more than two planes to avoid 2D circle solutions, with mirroring.
I still might be missing a loophole.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is exactly, but I interpret it as this.
Consider a finite set $A$ of points on the sphere $S^2$. We want it to have
the property that for each two points $a$, $b\in A$, there is a rotation
$R\in O(3)$ with $Ra=b$ and $R(A)=A$.

So each of these $R$ lies in the proper isometry group $G$ of $A$. This is a finite
group (unless $|A|\le2$), and it acts transitively on $A$.
So $|A|\le|G|$. The classification of finite subgroups
of $O(3)$ is known. They are cyclic, dihedral, tetrahedral, octahedral
and icosahedral.

I am sure the cyclic and dihedral groups will give you the configurations
you want to avoid, with points on two lines.

The largest polyhedral group is icosahedral of order $60$. I suspect
$60$ is your maximum number of points.

Comment: Sounds fair to me, though I wish the proof were simpler.  Is it easy to extend this solution to find the maximum number of points on a 4D sphere?

Comment: I don't think a group with $60$ elements can act transitively on more than $60$ points, so it would have to be the maximum. There is an Archimedean solid [with $120$ vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosidodecahedron) if OP decides to allow reflections too, but I think it's pretty safe to say that $60$ is the maximum (although there are a couple of point configurations to choose from).